# Undefined offset issue PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable `$newExtract[$x][3]`. When I try to explode it as:

```
explode("/", $newExtract[$x][3])
```

It gives me error message:

> "Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\torrent\classes\sm9.class.php on line 63".

But, when I echo it using `echo $newExtract[$x][3]; die();`, it gives me the result as `13/08/2012 20:58`.

Can anyone help me what is happening? Why, I am not able to explode it?

Thanks

Comment: what is o/p of var_dump($newExtract[$x][3]) ?

Comment: Is `$x` the same when you `explode()` and `echo`?

Comment: Show some context code - how are you getting `$newExtract` and `$x`? Are you performing `explode` and `die` in the same location?

Comment: yes x is same when I explode or echo

Comment: @GBD: the output of var_dump is: string(16) "13/08/2012 12:58"

Comment: @DCoder: yes, but alternatively. See at the time of exploding, it gave me this error, but then I did echo and bingo.. I got output. So this is confusing.

Comment: What is on line 63 sm9.class.php ? and is this object $newExtract[$x][3] ?

Comment: Did you place the var_dump just below the explode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen several places in PHP where *implicit* string conversion (or string dereferencing, in this case) causes issues and the simplest path to sanity is using an intermediate variable:

```
$date = $newExtract[$x][3];
explode("/", $date);
```

It seems to show up more often with certain internal functions, and I usually run into it more with objects and __toString(), but this wouldn't be the first time for this situation, either.

Comment: May be this is the problem with OP

Comment: May be because, I tried what ctrahey suggested but still the same problem.

Comment: In that case I revert to either a step debugger or rudimentary debugging to evaluate progressively up or down: is `$newExtract[$x]` what you think it is? etc..

Comment: thanks guys, I don't know..but it started working by itself. Just cleared my cache. Magic!!

Comment: Heh... that's when I start attempting to reproduce it again. Does the original case still cause the error?? Cheers!